# SSRS :Failed to convert nvarchar to int

Tags: reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

Hi 
I have a dataset as follows

SELECT     WEEKNAME AS WEEKSTART, CUSIP_BASE AS CUSIP,

case

when  FK_BBGFTPStatus = 5 then 'Failure'

when FK_BBGFTPStatus = 8 then 'Failure'

when FK_BBGFTPStatus = 9 then 'Failure'

when FK_BBGFTPStatus = 3 then 'Success'  end 'RESULT'

FROM         Glossary

WHERE     (FK_BBGFTPStatus = 5 OR

```
              FK_BBGFTPStatus = 8 OR
              FK_BBGFTPStatus = 9 OR
              FK_BBGFTPStatus = 3) AND (WEEKNAME BETWEEN @WeekStart AND @EndDate) and convert(varchar(10),FK_BBGFTPStatus) in (@Status)
```

i have a report parameter as follows

Name:Status
Datatype:string
Prompt:status
multivalue
Nonqueried

Label             Value

Success            3

Failure           '5','8','9'

it works fine for succes because it is just one number
i am getting an error when i check the checbox in the dropdownbox for failure

can you please help mee with this issue

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add a cast to put it in int.

I add this at the beginning (before the select):

```
DECLARE @tmp_Status integer;
set @tmp_Status = CAST(FK_BBGFTPStatus as int);
```

And then use everywhere the var @tmp_Status.